# Variable 'name' flashing at page load

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and I'm working through some tutorials, but can't seem to find out how to get a variable **{{ name }}** to quit flashing right before page load... Has anyone run into this problem before?

{{ name }} shows for a split second and then goes away. Just trying to get it to not show for a split second.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [ngcloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak) to suppress the html templates output before the actual binding occurs.

Answer (score 3):

ngCloak directive is used to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

For example:

```
<div id="template1" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
<div id="template2" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">{{ 'hello IE7' }}</div>
```

Comment: What to do if this is the title which flashes? Seems that ng-cloak has no effect on title tag

Answer (score 2):

Just following this up if it will help anyone, like kirhgoff, wondering how to sort this for the title element: ng-cloak will help to some extent, but you can fully prevent it using ng-bind directive instead of using {{ }}.

so:

```
<title ng-bind="pageTitle"></title>
```

not:

```
<title>{{pageTitle}}</title>
```

This avoids the issue ng-cloak solves entirely.

Comment: I liked your answer. Very useful. Thank you.